# SQL use full query in and

Tags: sql

Is there a way to use my last column as and

```
SELECT 
    BookingID, UnitID, SUM(DueTill) AS 'DueTill',
    (SELECT MAX(LetterTypeID) AS 'let' 
     FROM Letters AS l 
     WHERE ProjectID = 27 
       AND ScheduledDues.BookingID = l.BookingID) AS 'lettertype'   
FROM
    ScheduledDues 
WHERE
    ProjectID = 27  
GROUP BY 
    BookingID, UnitID
```

Like this and `ProjectID=27 having Max(LetterTypeID)=5`

Comment: See the `having` keyword in SQL

Comment: ok i corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT bookingid, 
       unitid, 
       Sum(duetill)                                       AS 'DueTill', 
       (SELECT Max(lettertypeid) AS 'let' 
        FROM   letters AS l 
        WHERE  projectid = 27 
               AND scheduleddues.bookingid = l.bookingid) AS 'lettertype' 
FROM   scheduleddues 
WHERE  projectid = 27 
GROUP  BY bookingid, 
          unitid 
          AND ` projectid = 27 
HAVING (SELECT Max(lettertypeid) AS 'let' 
        FROM   letters AS l 
        WHERE  projectid = 27 
               AND scheduleddues.bookingid = l.bookingid) = 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite it as:

```
Select s.BookingID,s.UnitID,
       Sum(s.DueTill) as 'DueTill',
       Max(l.LetterTypeID) as 'lettertype'   
from ScheduledDues s
left join Letters as l 
  on s.BookingID=l.BookingID
where s.ProjectID=27  
group by s.BookingID ,s.UnitID
having Max(l.LetterTypeID) = 5;
```